# Replace substring that lies between two positions

Tags: string, matlab, replace

I have a string `S` in Matlab. How can I replace a substring in S with some pattern `P`. I only know the first and the last index of substring in `S`. What is the approach?

Comment: @thewaywewalk, but it replaces all occurrences of the string "oldSubstr" in initial string. And I want to replace only one occurrences - that lies between 'first' and 'last'. Edit: I beg you a pardon for removing your comment - just mixed the buttons.

Comment: I deleted it by myself because I misread your question. Because I get you right, you don't have a pattern you want to substitute, you just know the indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about that?

```
str = 'My dog is called Jim';      %// original string  

a = 4;                             %// starting index
b = 6;                             %// last index

replace = 'hamster';               %// new pattern

newstr = [str(1:a-1) replace str(b+1:end)]
```

returns:

```
newstr =  My hamster is called Jim
```

---

In case the pattern you want to substitute has the same number of characters as the new one, you can use simple indexing:

```
str(a:b) = 'cat'
```

returns:

```
str =  My cat is called Jim
```